# Isotopy of open book supporting same contact structure

Tags: differential-topology, 3-manifolds, contact-geometry

In dimension 3, the Giroux correspondence gives us a bijection between contact structures (up to isotopy) and open book decompositions (up to positive stabilisation). Moreover, Giroux shows that two contact structures supported by the same open book are isotopic as contact structures. My question is a slight converse which I assume is true, but I can't find any explicit mention of it:

Fix a contact structure $\xi$ on a 3-manifold $M$, and let $(B,\pi)$ be an open book supporting $\xi$. i.e., there is a contact form $\alpha$ such that $\xi = \ker\alpha$, $d\alpha$ is symplectic on pages $\pi^{-1}(t)$ and $\alpha|_{B}>0$ where the orientation of $B$ is the induced by the orientation of the page it bounds. Without stabilising, what freedom do I have for the open book decomposition (while still fixing $\xi$)?

Clearly, there are many contact forms that give the same contact structure are their kernel. So if I perturb the contact form, does the open book decomposition change by an isotopy? If so, how do I show this?

Thankyou in advance for any help or references.

Comment: I think the answer to the questions, will be easier if one can associate to each OBD, a characteristic metric on the diffeomorphism group of the underlying manifold. One can surely define such a metric by looking for an extremal symplectisation of the contact structure. A way to obtain such an extremalization is by solving the Einstein-Yang-Mills Field Equations in the double null foliations jauge for the symplectisation and an adapted jauge (surely a specialization of a 't Hooft gauge) for the Yang-Mills fields.